# Sed $DISPLAY of currently logged in user

Tags: regex, linux, sed, xorg

I want to find out the used DISPLAY of the currently logged in user. For that I wanted to use `sed`. First, the output of `who`:

```
[orschiro@thinkpad ~]$ who
orschiro tty1         2013-08-05 23:15
orschiro pts/0        2013-08-05 23:17 (:0)
orschiro pts/1        2013-08-05 23:22 (:0)
orschiro pts/2        2013-08-05 23:22 (:0)
```

That is I want to retrieve `:0` for the logged in user `orschiro`.

I am using the following expression but it does not retrieve the expected result. Instead the output is empty:

```
[orschiro@thinkpad ~]$ who | sed -e "/orschiro/! d;/pts/d;s/^.*[^0-9]\\(:[0-9.]\\+\\).*$/\\1/p;d" | head -n1
[orschiro@thinkpad ~]$
```

What is wrong with my expression?

Comment: `/pts/d` will delete all the lines of interest. It would really help if you edited your question to include your required output, give the above input. Good luck.

Comment: The assumption that there can be exactly one logged-in user with a display is, of course, false in the general case.

Comment: True. I mean you could easily extend that approach by looping through he logged in users. In my case that was not necessary though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command `/pts/d;` delete all lines, that contain string `pts`.
Try this:

```
who | sed -e '/orschiro/! d; /pts/! d; s/^.*\(:[0-9.]\+\).*$/\1/p;d' | head -n1
```

Comment: Or better yet `who | sed -n '/^orschiro.*(\(:[0-9]*\))$/!d;s//\1/p;q'`

Comment: Yep, this definitely better, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```bsh
who | awk -F '[()]' '/orschiro/{print $(NF-1)}' | grep -v orschiro | head -n1
```

or

```
who | awk -F '[()]' '/orschiro/{print $(NF-1)}' | grep -v orschiro | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
who | awk '/orschiro/{print $5}' | sed -e 's/[()]//g'